# Specflow attributes

Tags: selenium, specflow

Can any one advice me on what the right specflow attribute or the right manner of approach to open just one Browser and run multiple feature files containing multiple scenarios
from looking at the documentation BEFORE SCENARIO And BEFORE FEATURE will both run 
multiple times if i have have multiple features and multiple scenarios.

Comment: What about the BeforeTestRun- Hook? http://specflow.org/documentation/Hooks/

Comment: I have just read the information on that and it looks like the correct attribute i will give it a try.    Thanks